# Magento getCollection is running out of memory

Tags: magento

In the OrderController.php, for address action ,

> $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
>               ->getCollection()
>               ->getItemById($addressId);

I get error 
**PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 3221225472 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 84 bytes**

Comment: are you tring to log this collection?

Comment: I am not trying to log.
I want to go to edit Address page. This page is coming blank.

Comment: ok then go with @Emipro answer..

Comment: i have memory limit = 3072M

Comment: Even after putting -1 for memory_limit its still the same..

Answer (score 0):

Increase your memory limit in server configuration.

In the `php.ini` file, update memory limit as follows.

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

And if you don't have acces to `php.ini` file, use `.htaccess` file to update section as follows.

```
...
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    ## other configuaration goes here
    php_value memory_limit 256M
</IfModule>
...
```

Comment: in php.ini file, I have the below line,,

@emipro

**<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 3072M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000 **